# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 6 column 16 path $.Valute

Tags: android, json, kotlin

Всем привет, я новенький в android. Пытаюсь получить список валют и показать его на экране, не могу понять в чем у меня ошибка. Json

```
"Valute": {
        "AUD": {
            "ID": "R01010",
            "NumCode": "036",
            "CharCode": "AUD",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Австралийский доллар",
            "Value": 53.2432,
            "Previous": 53.0553
        },
        "AZN": {
            "ID": "R01020A",
            "NumCode": "944",
            "CharCode": "AZN",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Азербайджанский манат",
            "Value": 43.0881,
            "Previous": 43.1616
        },
        "GBP": {
            "ID": "R01035",
            "NumCode": "826",
            "CharCode": "GBP",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Фунт стерлингов Соединенного королевства",
            "Value": 100.1687,
            "Previous": 100.2222
        },
        "AMD": {
            "ID": "R01060",
            "NumCode": "051",
            "CharCode": "AMD",
            "Nominal": 100,
            "Name": "Армянских драмов",
            "Value": 15.0653,
            "Previous": 14.9199
        },
        "BYN": {
            "ID": "R01090B",
            "NumCode": "933",
            "CharCode": "BYN",
            "Nominal": 1,
            "Name": "Белорусский рубль",
            "Value": 29.2429,
            "Previous": 29.5382
```

мой data class

```
data class ValuteInfo(

    @SerializedName("Valute")
    var valutes: ArrayList<Map<String, Valute>>
)

data class Valute(

    @SerializedName("CharCode")
    var charCode: String,
    @SerializedName("Nominal")
    var nominal: Int,
    @SerializedName("Name")
    var name: String,
    @SerializedName("Value")
    var value: Double
)
```

мой адаптер

```
class Adapter(
    @get:JvmName("getAdapterContext")
    var context: Context,
    var listLayout: Int,
    var valuteList: ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, Valute>>
) :
    ArrayAdapter<LinkedHashMap<String, Valute>>(
        context, listLayout,
        valuteList as ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, Valute>>
    ) {
    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): 
View {
        val inflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        val listViewItem = inflater.inflate(listLayout, null, false)

        val charCode = listViewItem.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.char_code)
        val nominal = listViewItem.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.nominal)
        val name = listViewItem.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.name)
        val value = listViewItem.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.value)

        try {
            charCode.text = valuteList.get(position).get("")!!.charCode.toString()
            charCode.text = valuteList.get(position).get("")?.charCode.toString()
            nominal.text = valuteList.get(position).get("")?.nominal.toString()
            name.text = valuteList.get(position).get("")?.name.toString()
            value.text = valuteList.get(position).get("")?.value.toString()

        } catch (je: JSONException) {
            je.printStackTrace()
        }
        return listViewItem
    }
}
```

как мне правильно получать валюты и отображать их в списке?

мой фрагмент `class ValueFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_value){

```
private val mApi: Api? = Api.Instance.getApi()


override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    btn_check.setOnClickListener{
        getValue()
    }
}

fun getValue(){
    mApi!!.getValute()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe {
            data -> getData(data)
        }
}

fun getData(data:ValuteInfo){
    var listitem: ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, Valute>> = arrayListOf()
    var adapter = Adapter(requireActivity(),R.layout.list_item,listitem)
    recycler_view.adapter = adapter
}
```

}`

Comment: где ваш список находится? покажите как вы в него данные загружаете, так пока сложно сказать где проблема, и опишите что именно не получается, это тоже пока не очень понятно

Comment: Список создаю в data class ValuteInfo. Я пытаюсь получить поля AUD,AZN,AMD. Так как у них у всех есть одинаковые поля, я хочу получить их списком и показывать их поля.

Comment: без класса где это все происходит сложно сказать где проблема, активность это или фрагмент? приложите код того как вы это делаете

Comment: @Andrew добавил фрагмент

Answer (score 1):

В `ValuteInfo` должно быть

```kotlin
var valutes: Map<String, Valute>
```

а не

```kotlin
ArrayList<Map<String, Valute>>
```